# How to extract contents of <span> which contains normal texts as well as other HTML tags in BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Using BeautifulSoup, I'm trying to extract the contents which is in between the `<span>` tags. I use `string` property to get the desired output. It works fine if the `<span>` tag contains only text. But it fails if the tag has some other HTML tags other than the normal text placed in it. E.g.

If I scrape the following:

```
<span>Elegant, Furnished, Planned</span>
```

Using the snippet:

```
soup.select_one('span').string
```

It works fine and I get the output as:

```
Elegant, Furnished, Planned
```

But, I get `None` when I scrape the following:

```
<span>Elegant, <b>Furnished</b>, Planned</span>
```

Help me to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work fine. Try with lxml

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
html = '''
<span>Elegant, Furnished, Planned</span>
'''
soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
soup.select_one('span').text
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this one:

```
url = 'your.example.net'
page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")

for span in soup.find_all('span'):
    print (span.text)
```